# How do I run a class compiled with jaotc?

Tags: java, java-9, jaotc

I compiled a simple class using the [Java 9](http://jdk.java.net/9/) Ahead-Of-Time Compiler [`jaotc`](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295) using the following command:

```
javac Test.java
jaotc Test.class
```

This produces a file named `unnammed.so`. How do I run the compiled program? Do I need to write a bootstrap program to link with the .so file?

Comment: The page you linked (of the compiler) has a section titled "Steps to generate and use an AOT library for the java.base module" - have you tried adapting the last part from that? e.g.: `java -XX:AOTLibrary=./unnamed.so Test`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After executing an AOT compilation, you need to specify generated AOT library during application execution:

```
java -XX:AOTLibrary=./Test.so Test
```

You should also compile `java.base` to gain real improvement, performance wise:

```
jaotc --output libjava.base.so --module java.base
```

Note that the same java runtime configuration should be used during AOT compilation and execution.

**For Example:**

```
jaotc -J-XX:+UseParallelGC -J-XX:-UseCompressedOops --output libTest.so Test.class 
java -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:-UseCompressedOops -XX:AOTLibrary=./libTest.so Test
```

Take a look at [this](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295), for more information.

Comment: I should add that you should also compile java.base because compiling Test class only will not give any performance gain

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that ArgOne should be the Java class name for the class to run.

Answer (score 5):

You should have a look at JEP 295, which describes AOT compilation in JDK 9, http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295.  You need to use the --XX::AOTLibrary command line flag.

To execute your app:

```
java -XX::AOTLibrary=./unnamed.so,./libjava.base.so Test
```

You will obviously have to copy the libjava.base.so file from the JDK 9 distribution or change the path to where it is.

When compiling you should also use the --output flag to jaotc so you don't get 'unnamed.so'.